# "They seated themselves (?) either side of Harry"

Tags: prepositions, transitivity

In Harry Potter III, my attention was caught by the following construction:

> Hermione and Ron were looking daggers at each other, and when they got
>   into class, **they seated themselves either side of Harry;**

Why the preposition **"on"**, or maybe another one, was not put before **"either side"**?

At first, I was thinking that the answer may be connected with the transitivity of the verb "seat", which was used here instead of the intransitive "sit" / "sit down". But then I searched for another examples in HP. That's what I have found:

> He and Hermione sat down on either side of Ron
>   They went to sit down either side of her.
>   the Bulgarian Beaters <..> had landed either side of Mostafa
>   <..> and settled themselves in chairs on either side of him.

I see virtually no difference between "on either side" and "either side". Am I right? Can I use them interchangeably in speech and writing?

Comment: The mean the same thing in the U.K. In the U.S., we usually say *on either side*.

Comment: [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=placed+on+either+side+of%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cplaced+either+side+of%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cplaced+on+either+side+of%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cplaced+either+side+of%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplaced%20on%20either%20side%20of%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplaced%20either%20side%20of%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplaced%20on%20either%20side%20of%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplaced%20either%20side%20of%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) for evidence.

Comment: Peter Shor, thank you. The link to Google Ngrams is very helpful. I wiil be aware of this tool from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an American English perspective, this is one of those constructions where "on either side" and "either side" **mean the same thing**, but there are differences. In a more archaic or extremely formal tone, one might drop the preposition here (or maybe emulating a more UK style). Spoken, this omission in the phrase would go unnoticed, although generally it's more correct to use the preposition "on". **In any type of writing, one can never go wrong by using "on".**